# Bot working on Emulator but not on Azure (InternalServerError)

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

Using:

- SDK Language: C#
- SDK Version: 4.1.5
- Enviroment: Localhost, Azure
- Channel: webchat

---

### **Issue Description**

When testing the bot in Bot Framework Emulator V4, it does work as expected as it can be seen in the next figure:

[image: Figure 1: Bot working on emulator]

After Deploying it in Azure following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-deploy-azure?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) instructions, bot stops working (neither sending or receiving messages) and got this alerts in the webchat channel section:

[image: Figure 2: Alerts at the channel section]

I've found these similar issues:

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/296

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3329

But in my case both AppId and Password are defined and the other solution simply doesn't work at all.
I even managed to find the error codes on the azure platform, but I was unable to find the details or get where the error is coming from...

[image: Figure 3: AppInsights Error panel]

### Code Overview

```
public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        bool reintentar = false;
        //tried this but didn't work
        //MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl("http://botrps.azurewebsites.net");         

        //obtener el contexto de los dialogos
        var dc = await _dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

        if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message && turnContext.Activity.From.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
        {
            //bot operations on users messages
        }    

        //if active dialog
        await dc.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);

        //else, start greeting dialog
        if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate &&
            turnContext.Activity.MembersAdded[0].Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
        {
            await dc.BeginDialogAsync("dialogo", null, cancellationToken);
        }

        await _accessors.ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);

        // Guarda los cambios realizados en el Contexto, si hay alguno
        await _accessors.UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Comment: Have you added a production endpoint to your bot file?

Comment: Does clicking on the "count" of the `invalidOperationException` in the log (application insights?) show you any kind of stack trace?

Comment: Thx for the answers. After adding production endpoint the bot seems to work fine, both in webchat and Skype.

By the way, I realised it's working whitout the "abs" service. It's also necessary to specify it?

Comment: No, it is not necessary to specify the 'abs' service as the production endpoint points to it. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by [tdurnford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10708483/tdurnford) in the comment section, it was necessary to add to the .bot configuration the production enpoint service. The resulting bot file:

```
{
  "name": "BotMod2",
  "services": [
    {
      "type": "endpoint",
      "name": "development",
      "endpoint": "http://localhost:3978/api/messages",
      "appId": "",
      "appPassword": "",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "appId": "**********************",
      "appPassword": "**********************",
      "endpoint": "https://**********************.azurewebsites.net/api/messages",
      "type": "endpoint",
      "name": "production",
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "appId": "**********************",
      "authoringKey": "**********************",
      "version": "0.1",
      "region": "westus",
      "type": "luis",
      "name": "**********************",
      "id": "3"
    },
    {
      "type": "qna",
      "name": "**********************",
      "kbId": "**********************",
      "hostname": "https://**********************.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker",
      "endpointKey": "**********************",
      "subscriptionKey": "**********************",
      "id": "4"
    }
  ],
  "padlock": "",
  "version": "2.0"
}
```